# Liberty Profile and Apache HttpClient 4.2.1

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, websphere-liberty

Not sure if others have seen this, but I can't figure out what the deal is...
I am using Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1 with IBM JDK 7 pxi3270sr5-20130619_01(SR5)

I have a class that needs to make URL requests to another server (PHP based). So I wrote a HttpHelper class to call the apache HttpClient classes. If I invoke my helper from a plain java application I have no problem. When I run the exact same code within Liberty I get a ClassNotFound Error for javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket

Here is my code that calls the apache classes...

```
    public class HttpClientHelper
    {
    static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HttpClientHelper.class.getName());
    static String cname = HttpClientHelper.class.getName();
    static HttpClientHelper _instance = null;
    static PoolingClientConnectionManager _cm = null;

    private HttpClientHelper()
    {
     SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
     schemeRegistry.register(
     new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

     _cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);

     _cm.setMaxTotal(200);

     _cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    HttpHost shost = new HttpHost("joomla32.cal2.net", 80);
    _cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(shost), 50);
   }
   protected static HttpClientHelper getInstance() {
if (_instance == null) {
  _instance = new HttpClientHelper();
}
return _instance;
    }

    public static String getUrlBody(String url) {
    String method = "getUrlBody(String url)";
    LOGGER.entering(cname, method, url);
getInstance();
String val = null;
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
try {
  HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(_cm);
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

  System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
  val = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
  EntityUtils.consume(entity);

} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.logp(Level.WARNING, cname, method, e.getMessage(), url);
}catch(Error e){
    LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO,cname,method,e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();

}
finally{

    LOGGER.exiting(cname, method, val);
}
return val;
     }
    }
```

\

The Error gets thrown at the httpclient.execute(httpget,context);

I have tried adding the ssl updates to the IBM JDK but that didn't work.
        ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
        ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... 
My HttpClient Helper class was packaged in a bundle as part of a feature. The bundle didn't import javax.net.ssl so the class couldn't find it. Doh.